# Spring MVC did not found mapping

Tags: spring-mvc

I decided to move into world of Java EE from SE. I analyzed where I should start and most appealing option was spring MVC. I am unable to move forward because mapping for page is just not found.

I already checked some solutions here on stackoverflow and also on other sites on internet. Everything looks like it should just work, but there are no expected results.

I am using Maven with this pom.xml configuration

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TDC</groupId>
    <artifactId>webApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>webApp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I would like to define servlet to handle pages using web.xml configuration

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>webApp</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>IndexPage</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>IndexPage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

IndexPage-servlet.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="tdc.web" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am starting application with class App.class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

Also using controller IndexController.class

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "MVC index page");
        return "index";
    }

}
```

And i want make application entry point at index.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.time.LocalDateTime"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Just title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Hello! Today is
        <%=LocalDateTime.now()%></p>
    <p>And now another messages ${message}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

My file structure is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEVkz.jpg

My expectation was to see page, but instead of this I only get default 404 error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkuur.jpg
Also i noticed in log of spring application Page not found exception and also, when registering new servlet it should be also logged right ? There is only mention about default servlet.

Here is application log

```
INFO 16860 --- [           main] tdc.web.App                              : Starting App v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on Cycan with PID 16860 (C:XXXX)
INFO 16860 --- [           main] tdc.web.App                              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
INFO 16860 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
INFO 16860 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
INFO 16860 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
INFO 16860 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
INFO 16860 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
INFO 16860 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3752 ms
INFO 16860 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
INFO 16860 --- [           main] tdc.web.App                              : Started App in 4.843 seconds (JVM running for 5.509)
INFO 16860 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
INFO 16860 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
INFO 16860 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 6 ms
WARN 16860 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /IndexPage
```

I am not sure what I missed. I will appreciate any answer :)

Comment: What URL are you entering in the browser? It looks like you are probably doing `http://localhost:8080/IndexPage` but your controller is mapped to `/`, so the correct URL would just be `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: I was using http://localhost:8080/IndexPage, also i forgot to mention when typing only localhost:8080 I will get status 500 with message: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Comment: That's because you're returning the string `index` from your controller.  Based on the way you have your `viewResolver` set up, that means Spring is going to look for a file named index.jsp in the WEB-INF/views directory, so your index page must not be in that directory.

Comment: Have you tried renaming your `dispatcherServlet` to `dispatcherServlet` instead of `IndexPage`?  The dispatcherServlet isn't really like a traditional servlet that services page requests, it's a front controller that delegates to your controller classes.

Comment: renaming to ```dispatcherServlet``` result in same behavior. You also mentioned that index.jsp MUST NOT BE in directory WEB-INF/views, where should i put it then if it is not a typo ?

Comment: You can check this topic https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/

Comment: @Cycan You misunderstood my comment, what I meant is that index.jsp HAS to be in the WEB-INF/views but seems like it is not the case.